# creating derbyjs app in windows

Tags: node.js, derbyjs

probably a stupidd question. I have installed node.js on my Windows 7 machine and and trying to install derbyjs. i ran the "npm install -g derby" command and everything seemed fine.

Now when i try to create a new app via

```
 derby new --coffee testProj01
```

it gives me the error that derby is not a recognized command. I tried running the new project command from the node_modules/derby/bin directory as well. now it shows the "choose an application to open selected file" popup.

i guess the problem is that there is no exe in the bin folder. Am i supposed to build derby before i can work on it?
How do I do that?

Comment: I too have worked on W7, for me `derby new project` worked fine and I could use the basic `hello` app. However at this point in time Windows impelementation of derby is quite buggy. Most of the apps won't work on Windows including sink and todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derby and the libraries it depends on are now working again on Windows as of v0.3.8. Do a node install and a npm update and you should be good.

See https://github.com/codeparty/derby/issues/42 for background.